# Python-check if the input which is a two lists of numbers from the user contains only numbers (all types, including fractions and negative numbers)

Tags: python, input, type-conversion

(in Python 3)
I neet to check if the input which is two lists of numbers from the user contains only numbers and than calculate pearson corelation.
**requierments:**
-All types of numbers, including fractions and negative numbers.
-The user can type extra spaces or no spaces at all, it shouldn't metter.
-There must be a comma, between the numbers.
-It needs to be simple, no libaries or advanced functions.
-If an element in a list from the user is not a number, he need to see the message: "was not able to calculate the correlation" and than the code stops.

the clue i got:

two ways were offer to solve it:

1. use:starts with,strip,split - also possible to divide by commas. It is possible if you want to break it down before and after the point.,all and list comprehension - requires creativity.
   2.Run over the characters of the number (with for) and make sure everything is digit and also allow one dot in the middle.

**An example of an output:**
Enter list1: 1,2,3, 5, 8
Enter list2: 0.11, 0.1, 0.13,0.2, 0.18
The correlation between the lists is: 0.83

Thanks

I've tried to convert all to float but if it contains something not a number i get an error. and i have to be able to get fragments like 0.18 ect.

```
list1=input("Enter list1:")
#Creates a list from string input
list1=list1.split(",")
#Check if all elements in list1 are numbers
check_list1_num = all(ele1.isdigit() for ele1 in list1)
#Same process for list2
list2=input("Enter list2:")
list2=list2.split(",")
check_list2_num = all(ele2.isdigit() for ele2 in list2)
if check_list1_num==True and check_list2_num==True:
list1 = [ float(i) for i in list1 ]
list2 = [ float(k) for k in list2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and except statements must be used if any unexpected input is given by user

```
try:
    list1=input("Enter list 1")
    list2=input("Enter list 2")
    lst1=list(map(float,[x.strip() for x in list1.split(',')]))
    lst2=list(map(float,[x.strip() for x in list2.split(',')]))
    corelation_function(list1,list2)
except Exception as e:
    print("was not able to calculate the correlation")
```

Here we split the input and strip of white spaces from both side and then covert it to float.
Any error will raise exception and code will stop.

Comment: Thanks. I run the code but the output is incorrect, even when I put a list of ints it didn't work: Enter list 1:7,7,5
Enter list 2:6,3,4
was not able to calculate the correlation

Comment: In the description you told about spaces and comma only,having colon in list break the code.If a user can type any symbol as a seperator than coversion cannot be done with just list comprehension.need to add more code for other symbols.